# Iterate over jinja array

Tags: python, jinja2

I have the following jinja array:

```
{'e34': ['120'], 'e24': ['50']}
```

I want to find if a word contains `e2`, and take it to another function.

I did the following:

```
{% set result = 'default' %}
{% for item, value in jinjaarray.items() %}
   {% if 'e2' in item %}
      result = item
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But it fails, and doesn't enter to the loop.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead using [`.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) like Python3, jinja2 uses Python2-fashioned [`.iteritems()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) as stated in the [docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#for).

Additionally, you need to [assign](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#assignments) the variable `result` to the `item` from the dictionary using `set`:

```
from jinja2 import Template

d = {'e34': ['120'], 'e24': ['50']}

s = """{% set result = 'default' %}
{% for item, value in test_dict.items() %}
   {% if 'e2' in item %}
      {% set result = item %}
      {{ result }}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}"""

template = Template(s)
print(template.render(test_dict=d))
```

Since I am using Python3 on my system I had to call `.items()`. Depending on your version you might call `.iteritems()` instead.

Since I do not have a jinja2 sandboxing environment set up on my system I had to wrote a quick and dirty code snippet as shown above. This delivers the following output:

```
'\n\n   \n      \n      e24\n   \n\n   \n'
```

Optically speaking this is not that nice, but it prints out the desired value of `e24`.

Comment: It still doesn't enter to the loop... I notice that result is not updated.

Comment: Could you please add a minimal working example to your question in order to get some code running on my system?

Comment: When I print the jinjaarray it gives me the following result: `{'e34': ['120'], 'e24': ['50']}`. This array is taken from external software so I can't write you example. So in result, I should get `e24` but instead I get `default` (after the loop is finished).